# What did I do wrong with my MessagesBloc class and how should I create it?

Tags: android, flutter, mobile, bloc

I have a component that is rendering a list view, but I'm wondering what is the best practice of structuring this? Should I use the messages list from the bloc state or should I have a local list in the component ?

```
 List<Message> messages = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onMessage: $message");

        var result = Message.fromMap(
            new Map<String, dynamic>.from(message['notification']));

        BlocProvider.of<MessagesBloc>(context).add(
          AddMessage(message: result),
        );

        setState(() {
          messages.add(result);
        });
      },
  }

    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
           return BlocBuilder<MessagesBloc, MessagesState>(
        builder: (context, state) {
      if (state is Loading) {
        return LoadingIndicator();
      }
      if (state is Finished) {
        messages = state.messages;
        return messages.length != 0
            ? _buildMessageView(messages)
            : _buildEmptyMessageView();
      }
    });
};
```

I am currently using firebase cloud messaging and my component is using the MessageBloc, with this state:

```
class MessagesBloc extends Bloc<MessagesEvent, MessagesState> {
  final DatabaseService databaseService;
  List<Message> _messages;

  MessagesBloc({@required this.databaseService})
      : assert(databaseService != null);

  @override
  MessagesState get initialState => Loading();

  @override
  Stream<MessagesState> mapEventToState(
    MessagesEvent event,
  ) async* {
    if (event is LoadingStarted) {
      _messages = // Getting notification from local db
    }

    if (event is Finished) {
      //
      print("finished loading messages");
    }

    if (event is AddNotification) {
      // yield Loading();
      // Add a message to DB

      _messages.add(event.message);

      yield Finished(messages: _messages);
    }

    if (event is ClearMessages) {
      // DELETE ALL MESSAGES FROM DB
      _messages = List<Message>();

      yield Finished(messages: _messages);
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my State

```
abstract class MessagesState extends Equatable {
  const MessagesState();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class Loading extends MessagesState {}

class Finished extends MessagesState {
  final List<Message> messages;

  const Finished({@required this.messages});

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [messages.length];
}
```

Here is my Events:

```
abstract class MessageEvent extends Equatable {
  const MessageEvent();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}
class Refreshing extends MessageEvent {}

class LoadingStarted extends MessageEvent {}

class LoadingFinished extends MessageEvent {
  final List<Message> messages;

  const LoadingFinished({@required this.messages});

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [messages];

  @override
  String toString() => 'Loaded notifications: $messages}';
}

class ClearMessages extends MessageEvent {}

class AddMessage extends MessageEvent {
  final Message message;

  const AddMessage({@required this.message});

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [message];
}
```

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no BlocProvider in parent widget, you need to make a bloc instance and give a bloc to BlocBuilder.

```
MessageBloc _messageBloc = MessageBloc(databaseService: someDatabaseServicInstance);
...

    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
           return BlocBuilder<MessagesBloc, MessagesState>(
        bloc: _messageBloc,
        builder: (context, state) {
      if (state is Loading) {
        return LoadingIndicator();
      }
      if (state is Finished) {
        messages = state.messages;
        return messages.length != 0
            ? _buildMessageView(messages)
            : _buildEmptyMessageView();
      }
    });
};
```

Comment: Well..If MessageBloc is used many child, I think BlocProvider is a good.
I usually made a one bloc and initiate bloc per page and use like upper case.
I don't know what is a good.

Comment: Hm.. It looks good.
When fcm message is came, you call ```messageBloc.add(AddMessage(message: msg));``` and add a BlocListener for 'AddMessage's complete and Loading message again for page update.
at first you load notifications from db but there is no saving routine added notifications to db.

Comment: I would like to test using bloc.
In 'Loading Started' event, return local message data and call addMessage at somewhere or temporal floating button or and so on.

Comment: Are 2 answers needed? Could they be merged?

Answer (score 0):

fcm message comes -> AddMessage
-> BlocListener listen AddMessageComplete event
-> replace messages variable from state.messages
(you should add AddMessage event's state like AddMessageFinished or AddMessageComplete)

```
List<Message> messages = [];
MessageBloc _messageBloc = BlocProvider.of<MessagesBloc>(context);

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onMessage: $message");

        var result = Message.fromMap(
            new Map<String, dynamic>.from(message['notification']));

         // I exactly don't know it works, if not works use yours.
        _messageBloc.add(
          AddMessage(message: result),
        );

        //setState(() {
        //  messages.add(result);
        //});
      },
  }

    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return BlocConsumer<MessagesBloc, MessagesState>(
        listener: (context, state) {
           if (state is AddCompleted) {
              setState(() {
                messages = state.messages;
              }
           }
        },
        builder: (context, state) {
          if (state is Loading) {
            return LoadingIndicator();
          }
          if (state is Finished) {
            messages = state.messages;
            return messages.length != 0
                ? _buildMessageView(messages)
                : _buildEmptyMessageView();
          }
        },
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: I recomand to use 'AddMessageComplete'.
When  state is 'Finish', if you yield same 'Finish', there is no state change and notifying and no rebuild maybe...

Comment: I have a one idea. When you yield AddMessageComplete, yield with just added message one.
And at the Bloc listener just add state one new message to 'messages' variable.
I think it will take off some load.